# Concurrency - Looping over large data set and performing action

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

**Some Background**

So I'm currently developing for a game project that I joined extracurricularly and was really made aware of the consequences of threading issues and concurrency over the last year or so.

One of the big issues we had back then was shutting down the server and saving: disconnecting all the clients and saving them proved to be an issue as we would run into concurrency issues. Though we solved that, I've been approached again with another possible concurrency problem.

**Issue**

I'm currently working on a Halloween event for the game and there is supposed to be a *global* event every once in awhile where all players online at that specific time receive a gift directly in their inventory.

Normally, I would have thought about grabbing the current set of players online and running through them all and just giving them an item, but I believe there are consequences with that.

*Immediate possible issues*

1. If a player logs out while iterating over the set I may get issues. However, we did wrap the structure that keeps track of players and their status with a thread-safe hash map. Does this mean that if I first execute to give out the reward, if a player tries to log out they will be forced to stay until the code for giving all the rewards out has finished executing? I'm not exactly writing or changing anything to the data structure, so I'm worried that the log out will go through and I'm trying to give an item to a person who has already logged out.
2. If a player logs in, they won't be in the current iteration of the gift cycle. Perhaps that's a good thing since once the gift handling is already underway, those who join are technically late.

I was wondering if there is a better way at tackling this problem. Perhaps I can have the gifts distribute to a central location where players can come and pick it up later, thus avoiding that huge looping over possibly hundreds and hundreds of players. *We did have issues with concurrency at ~200 online players*.

**MVE**

I wasn't quite sure what to provide as an MVE here since I'm talking about the concept of iterating over a large dataset and the concurrency issues related with it, which I don't think is very easily replicated(?). If I'm wrong I'll do my best to provide a code-related one.

Comment: Do you mean you have some internal technical issues that prevent you from giving the gift after user signs out?

Comment: @BasilBourque I was thinking that there may be some dynamic that may occur during the gifting process where I loop over all current users and distribute the gift, like if they log out, disconnect unexpectedly, etc. Since I'm simply reading over the structure by looping and giving them the gift, the removing of the user should technically go through, which in turn might mean I'm giving a present to a player object who is no longer logged in(?). That is one of my primary concerns.

Comment: Isn't the gift registered in a data store server-side? I understand being logged-in to *qualify* for the gift is your business rule. But why should being logged-in be a requirement to *receive* the gift? Just add the gift to their account stored on the server. All you should need is their account identifier. Or is the gift only stored client-side?

Comment: @BasilBourque Great! I had that in mind as well~ I'll change the method of receiving the gift so that instead of depositing it into the player's inventory, have it log and have the player retrieve it from a central area (kind of like a UPS for the game).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, there would be no internal technical limitations requiring a user to be signed in to receive the gift. But it sounds like you do have such issues.

## Weak reference

If the user objects you collect in order to give gifts become candidates for garbage collection upon user signing out, then your gift-giving collection should hold [weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) to those user objects. A weak reference allows garbage collection to proceed whereas a regular strong reference would disqualify the referenced object from becoming a candidate for garbage collection. See [`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) class.

Create an empty `List` or `Set`.

```
List< WeakReference< User > > u = new ArrayList< User >() ;
```

Iterate through your currently logged-in users. Wrap each user-object in a `WeakReference`. For gift-giving, iterate this second List/Set, checking each `WeakReference` to see if its referent is still available, and if so, give the gift. If not, move on to the next.

```
WeakReference< User > weakUser = new WeakReference<>( user );
u.add( weakUser ) ;
```

Once collected, wrap that list to be immutable, as a habit.

```
List< WeakReference< User > > users = Collections.unmodifiableList( u );
```

Actually, such an unmodifiable List/Set of `WeakReference` objects is what should be emitted by your user-management module whenever you ask for currently-logged-in users. Those users could be logging out at any moment, even when assembling that initial list/set. And always emit a freshly instantiated new collection, a copy of the one maintained internal to your user-management module. So your gift-giving code should not have to perform this work if building a new List/Set of `WeakReference`; that work should already have been done on its behalf.

By the way… If you have multiple cores in production, and want to get fancy, you could feed your collection of `WeakReference` objects to the new Java 8 Streams feature, to be automatically split up for parallel processing of your gift-giving.

Tip: You seem to be too worried about performance, and not worried enough about concurrency.

- Creating a collection of elements wrapped in a WeakReference is very fast, not an issue. Assigning references in memory takes almost no time.
- In contrast, concurrency is *always* an issue regardless of load, in contradiction to your comment about 200 users. **Even a *single* user could coincidentally be logging off during your gift-giving.** Programmers typically have a hard time grasping the irony that rare events happen all the time! Even worse, in a production environment, add in [*Murphy's Law*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law). Concurrency is harsh, capricious, and arbitrary.

Tip: Read and reread the book [*Java Concurrency In Practice*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/127932.Java_Concurrency_in_Practice) by [Brian Goetz](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/briangoetzchief-188795.html), Oracle’s *Java Language Architect*. I'm on my fifth reread.

Comment: I definitely did consider that! I came here just in case there was a better solution since that would involve creating a copy of the collection by wrapping it with a weak reference, right? Technically O(N^2) since I would have to go through and make a weak reference collection, then loop over again and gift? It is possible my O(Notation) is off though.

Comment: @Jon No, you must hold a strong (normal) reference to the collection itself. The elements held *inside* the collection must each be wrapped in a `WeakReference`. Alternatively, you may be able to find an implementation of a `List` or `Set` that does that wrapping on its own, transparent to you. But not a big deal to do the wrapping yourself, as you add each logged-in user. After building the collection, you iterate, testing each weak reference to see if your object is still available for gifting or not.

Comment: Sounds great :). Thank you for your insight!